# How could I implement token authentication in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

How could I implement token authentication in Sinatra?

Currently I use Rails 3.1 [token authentication](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L385).

Comment: You could check out this SO Answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091637/sinatra-omniauth-android-advice-sought)